# Getting related data from a collection result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I retrieved a collection of locations by id of a Firm. One firm can have many locations. Now I'm trying to retrieve staff from a location. One location can have many staff members.

- Model: `Firm` - hasMany relationship function called: `firmLocations`.
- Model: `Location` - belongsTo relationship function called `Firm`. Also had a hasMany function called `Staff`.
- Model: `Staff` - belongsTo relationship function called `Location`.

`Staff` model only relates with `Location` model.

Code is in a show function in a controller.

I thought now that I have related locations for a particular firm I can just use that collection to get staff members. However, I've hit a roadblock and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```php
public function showFirm($id)
{
    // Get locations of a firm by id
    $firm_locations = Firm::find($id)->firmLocations;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve Staff based on location along with firm.

```
public function showFirm($id) {

    // Get locations of a firm by id with staff member from location

    $firm_locations = Firm::where('id',$id)->with('firmLocations.staff')->first();

    // Above function retrieve Firm with Location and Location will have staff.
}
```

---

**I am assuming you've set up relationship correctly and you've working knowledge of relationship.**

Comment: Thank you! Greatly appreciated it. That did work. Yes, I do have the model relationships set up correctly.